How does lycra compare with neoprene gear in terms of jellyfish sting protection?
I wonder how lycra compares with neoprene gear in terms of jellyfish sting protection. (e.g.,  a lycra wetsuit vs. a neoprene wetsuit). Do they offer the same level of production against jellyfish stings?

I think you would need to compare like-with-like, say an 8mm wetsuit might offer 100% protection but a lycra suit might only be 0.5 mm thick. Australia sells lots of "stinger suits" for box jellyfish and irukandji which seem to be made from a mix of materials.

First a quick warning/disclaimer:  Jellyfish stings can be anything from a nuisance to fatal (e.g. Box Jellyfish, Irukandji Jellyfish, and Lion's Mane Jellyfish) depending on the person and the jellyfish involved (both can play a role in the reaction to a sting).  So fully research what's appropriate for your situation.  Don't make life decisions based on information provided by a "rando on the interwebs" (that's me, in this context).
Lycra is typically used for very thin rash guards, bodysuits, and dive skins.  Neoprene, on the other hand, is almost always much thicker (anywhere from 1mm to 8mm is common, and you can get thicker for colder waters).
Although I can't answer your question scientifically or empirically, I think neoprene wetsuits will give you better protection than Lycra.  You'll want good high booties and long gloves as well (cover those ankles and wrists!).  Lobster diving gloves may do well to prevent jellyfish stings; some have one or more Kevlar layers (note: Kevlar is woven, so you'll definitely want to see if that could be an issue with jellyfish).
There are also specialized materials out there that are neither Lycra nor neoprene.  If you'll be in warm waters where neoprene is too hot, but want more protection than Lycra may offer, you can search out these alternatives (I don't want to "shill" for any particular companies, and they pretty much all use propriety trademarked names for their materials).
On a final note, as "bob1" mentioned in the comments, some companies sell specific "stinger" wetsuits.  Those are beyond the scope of your question, but may be of interest to you.

Thanks! "I don't want to "shill" for any particular companies, and they pretty much all use propriety trademarked names for their materials" I'd be curious to know a few names, that'd help find others too.

You're welcome Franck.  The one I think the most highly of is "SharkSkin".  I'm not sure if they still make their rugged products.  But at least at one point, they made an incredibly durable fabric (the eponymous SharkSkin) that seemed resistant to almost anything.  I can't say how it would do against jellies, but it's the first product I would research if you want something really thin and tough.
